# MySQL - UNION SELECT with RLIKE and GROUP BY - not able to insert INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql, group-by, left-join, inner-join, union

I created a mySQL query to search words and order results by relevancy (Sortkey). For example, if I search "test word", my query will look like this (and it works like a charm):

```
SELECT * 
FROM (  SELECT *, 1 as SortKey 
        FROM equipments 
        WHERE (
            DESCRIPTION RLIKE '[[:<:]]test word[[:>:]]' 
            OR EQUIPMENT_ID RLIKE '[[:<:]]test word[[:>:]]' 
            OR CATEGORY RLIKE '[[:<:]]test word[[:>:]]'
        )

        UNION SELECT *, 2 as SortKey 
        FROM equipments 
        WHERE (
                (DESCRIPTION RLIKE '[[:<:]]test[[:>:]]' OR 
                EQUIPMENT_ID RLIKE '[[:<:]]test[[:>:]]' OR 
                CATEGORY RLIKE '[[:<:]]test[[:>:]]' OR 
                DESCRIPTION RLIKE '[[:<:]]tests[[:>:]]' OR 
                EQUIPMENT_ID RLIKE '[[:<:]]tests[[:>:]]' OR 
                CATEGORY RLIKE '[[:<:]]tests[[:>:]]') 

                AND

                (DESCRIPTION RLIKE '[[:<:]]word[[:>:]]' OR 
                EQUIPMENT_ID RLIKE '[[:<:]]word[[:>:]]' OR 
                CATEGORY RLIKE '[[:<:]]word[[:>:]]' OR 
                DESCRIPTION RLIKE '[[:<:]]words[[:>:]]' OR 
                EQUIPMENT_ID RLIKE '[[:<:]]words[[:>:]]' OR 
                CATEGORY RLIKE '[[:<:]]words[[:>:]]')
            )

        UNION SELECT *, 3 as SortKey 
        FROM equipments 
        WHERE (
                (DESCRIPTION RLIKE '[[:<:]]test[[:>:]]' OR 
                EQUIPMENT_ID RLIKE '[[:<:]]test[[:>:]]' OR 
                CATEGORY RLIKE '[[:<:]]test[[:>:]]' OR 
                DESCRIPTION RLIKE '[[:<:]]tests[[:>:]]' OR 
                EQUIPMENT_ID RLIKE '[[:<:]]tests[[:>:]]' OR 
                CATEGORY RLIKE '[[:<:]]tests[[:>:]]')
                ) 
                OR (
                (DESCRIPTION RLIKE '[[:<:]]word[[:>:]]' OR 
                EQUIPMENT_ID RLIKE '[[:<:]]word[[:>:]]' OR 
                CATEGORY RLIKE '[[:<:]]word[[:>:]]' OR 
                DESCRIPTION RLIKE '[[:<:]]words[[:>:]]' OR 
                EQUIPMENT_ID RLIKE '[[:<:]]words[[:>:]]' OR 
                CATEGORY RLIKE '[[:<:]]words[[:>:]]')
            )

) T1 GROUP BY EQUIPMENT_ID ORDER BY `SortKey` ASC
```

So, as I said, it works but I want to insert INNER JOIN in my query and I tried to put it everywhere and nothing works. Usually, to display all results without looking for keywords, I use this query (once again, it works fine):

```
SELECT
    `equipments`.`DESCRIPTION`,
    `equipments`.`EQUIPMENT_ID`,
    `equipments`.`CATEGORY`,
    `live_data`.`SERVICE`,
    `live_data`.`HOURS` 
FROM equipments 
INNER JOIN customers ON `customers`.`EQUIPMENT_ID` = `equipments`.`EQUIPMENT_ID`
LEFT JOIN live_data ON `live_data`.`EQUIPMENT_ID` = `equipments`.`EQUIPMENT_ID`
WHERE `customers`.`customer_id` = 1
```

I need to insert INNER JOIN to also add the WHERE statement to search into the customer's equipments only. Please help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select innerresult.* From
( Insert your query here ) innerresult
inner join customers On customers.equipment_id = innerresult.equipment_id
Where customers.customer_id = 1
```

Should do it I think.

Comment: Upon reflexion, I also need to get "SERVICE" and "HOURS" values from the table "live_data". I add the line "LEFT JOIN live_data ON live_data.EQUIPMENT_ID = innerresult.EQUIPMENT_ID" between the INNER JOIN line and the WHERE line but I don't know how to select "service" and "hours"... I tried a few things, but that wasn't successful...